# Adding local ttf fonts using @font_face in CSS

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am trying to add a local font to a site I am testing. It is called "AcrosstheRoad.ttf" and can be found in my assets/fonts/ folder. I am doing the following to try to read it into the CSS file:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'AcrosstheRoad';
  src: url('assets/fonts/AcrosstheRoad.ttf')  format('truetype');
}
```

And I want to use it as a certain header type so I am using

```
h3{
font-family: 'AcrosstheRoad';
color: #333;
}
```

But unfortunately the font is not loading in. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!
Christina

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First add a slash before `assets`:

```
(('/assets/fonts/AcrosstheRoad.ttf'))
```

That may or may not be the problem, depending on where your CSS file is, and how your website is structured.

If the above doesn't work, convert the font to `.woff2` and `.woff` (try using this: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator). The reasoning behind this is that some browsers are really picky. Change your CSS to:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'AcrosstheRoad';
  src:  url('/assets/fonts/AcrosstheRoad.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('/assets/fonts/AcrosstheRoad.woff') format('woff');,
       url('/assets/fonts/AcrosstheRoad.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the reply, I did the conversion and changed the slash and it's still not using the font I'm afraid. I have a ttf, woff and woff2 file in the /assets/fonts/ directory and I'm now calling with


`@font-face {
  font-family: 'AcrosstheRoad';
  src:  url('/assets/fonts/AcrosstheRoad.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('/assets/fonts/AcrosstheRoad.woff') format('woff'),
  url('/assets/fonts/AcrosstheRoad.ttf') format('truetype');
}`


and

`h3{
    font-family: 'AcrosstheRoad';
    color: #333;
}`

Comment: @Christina - Bill is correct, your path is the problem, if you `css` lives in `assets/css/whatever.css` then you can rectify the problem by setting the path for the font to `../fonts/AcrosstheRoad.ttf`.

Comment: First off, let's get the slash thing straight. Is your file in `http://something.tld/assets/fonts/AcrosstheRoad.ext`?

Comment: @Adam Urgh! I was putting the path relative to the index file not the CSS folder you're completely right! I feel silly! But now my font works, phew! Thanks for the help!