# @font-face is not working. Am I missing something?

Tags: css

I have a project directory:

```
.
├──fonts/
│  └──Roboto-Regular.ttf
├──images/
│  ├──final_goal.png
│  └──logo.png
├──scripts/
│  └──script.js
├──sites/
├──styles/
│  ├──style.css
│  ├──style.css.map
│  └──style.scss
├──code.sh
├──index.html
└──watch.sh
```

My CSS file is referenced in the `index.html` file. I try to make a font-face for the Roboto-Regular font using the following CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: GoogleRob;
    src:     url(/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

Which I later on reference with:

```
* {
    color: white;
    font-family: GoogleRob, monospace; /* here */
    font-size: small;
    padding: 0;
}
```

But it isn't working. Am I missing something in the syntax? I tried using different quote-marks and file-pathing conventions, but it does not work.

Please help

Comment: One of the things I'm trying to cover in this learning experience is using local fonts for my projects. Roboto is a safe choice for now, but I want to be capable of using a different (local) font if the situation asks for it. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: That makes sense - when I was testing, I found that the .tff font worked when I pushed it to prod, but wasn't working on a local server. 

Somebody else explores this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30020488/adding-local-ttf-fonts-using-font-face-in-css) - Good luck!

Comment: For Chrome and other modern browsers, don't use ttf, use woff2. That being said, try `url(../fonts/...)` as your path. How are you serving your page?

Comment: My index.html is in the root. For more detail, check the first code-block of my post. I will try converting it to woff/woff2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `style.css` file is in `styles` folder, beside the `fonts` folder, but in `url()` you didn't correctly address it. you should write like this:

```
src: url('../fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf') format("truetype");
```

With `../` you up one level from current folder( `styles` folder ), and then go into the `fonts` folder.

Answer (score 1):

`.ttf` font files don't work much on Google Chrome. Instead, always use `woff` and `woff2`.
Generally, it is recommended, to use both `.woff` and `.woff2`. Use **Woff2** as primary font, and **Woff** as fallback font, this ensures that the browser always uses the best font.

#### CSS Syntax

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: myWoffFont;
  src: url(fonttemplate.woff2);
}
@font-face {
  font-family: myWoffFont2;
  src: url(fonttemplate2.woff);
}
```

#### HTML

```html
div {
  font-family: fonttemplate, fonttemplate2;
}
```

*TTF can be useful to some older browsers. WOFF compresses the files and is supported by all modern browsers.*
[image]

Comment: Nice answer, but have you seen the other one?